# Xcode console input not matching output C++

Tags: macos, xcode, c++, string

I'm experiencing some weird problem writing C++ code in Xcode on a MacBook. I know the code isn't faulty as I have had windows users run it with no problems at all, but somehow the output I get is not matching the input most of the time. I have tried to reinstall Xcode to no avail.
Here is the code that I'm running:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::string test = "";
    while (std::cin >> test) {
        std::cout << test << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the console from within Xcode to give user input, here are some examples of the output I get:

Input: 1+(2+2)

Output: 1+()2+2

Input: 2*(-(8/2))

Output: 2*()()-8/2

Comment: The boxes displays some type of question mark symbols, looks like it won't show when pasted here though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. It always echos back what I just typed, as expected.Tried several times. With debug and release build settings. Are you using the Console window in XCode to run this or a separate terminal ?

Comment: @Tonny Thanks for the reply. I am using the console window in Xcode. It happens to me every time I have typed an input and then have moved the text cursor using the arrow keys, as if it is somehow trying to read the arrow keys as input. I'm not sure, but if that is the case do you know how I could fix that, making it stop reading the arrow keys as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment regarding the cursor keys clarified the issue.
Normally the C/C++ runtime stdio libraries rely on the system's terminal implementation to deal with special keys like cursors so the program will receive so-called "cooked" terminal input, where all the weirdness is filtered out.
Unfortunately the Console window inside XCode isn't a proper terminal and some things come through.
This something specific to XCode and its Console window. It shouldn't happen when the compiled program is run from a normal Terminal window. Pressing the cursors there will generate some weird characters on screen, but they won't arrive on std::cin.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, do you know of any workarounds to this problem other than using the normal Terminal window, or maybe some way I could fix this so that I can continue to use the Console within Xcode? If not, could you recommend me another good C++ compiler for macOS?

Comment: @matdoz No way around it except by NOT using the Console-window in XCode, which is very inconvenient. You are not looking for another C++ compiler. You want a different IDE. JetBrains has CLion (not free). CodeBlocks was a contender, but the Mac fork isn't developed since 2013. That leaves Eclipse (very complicated to install/configure). Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac doesn't do C/C++ (yet). Of course you can use any good code-editor with the command line compiler, but that won't give you integrated debugging. To be honest: I would just live with the Console quirks.